# Get row from array by ID

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have a custom array called IOfficeInfo like this:

```html
export class IOfficeInfo {
        OfficeID: number;
        TypeOfOffice: string;
        DateSubmitted: string;
        OfficeName: string;
}
```

I want to create a blank array of that same type, then insert one office into that blank array where the OfficeID equals an existing number.  My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to select that one one office from the data array and push it into the blank array.

Once I get this working I will then insert the remaining offices from the data array sorted chronologically.  I know it is a weird requirement, but I wasn't the one making them.  I just have to do as I am told.

Here is how I am handling the sortOfficeInfo function.  While debugging, I can see the data passed into the method.  The data.sort works fine.  Again, my problem is getting the one office and pushing it into the blank array (returnarray).  Specifically, topOffice is undefined.

```js
  sortOfficeInfo(data: IOfficeInfo[]): IOfficeInfo[] {
    // The first item has to be the enrollment that the user clicked.
    // The remaining enrollments are dupes that are required to be ordered by date submitted
    let returnarray: IOfficeInfo[] = [];
    let topoffice: IOfficeInfo = data.find(x => x.OfficeID === this.OfficeID);

    data.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a.DateSubmitted < b.DateSubmitted) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.DateSubmitted > b.DateSubmitted) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    debugger;
    returnarray.push(topoffice);
    return returnarray;
  }
```

My Question:
How do I select the row by OfficeID and how to I push it into the returnarray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geeze ...
The problem was that the OfficeID was a string, and it has to be a number.